# How can i insert print button on each accordion?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

So i have created multiple accordions, on my php webpage. I want a print button on each of them so user can print it out, in my format. Here is the code:

PHP:

```
for($i=0; $i<$length; $i++) //Length is usually between 3-6
{  
  echo "<div id='nestedAccordion'>";
     echo "<h2><table><thead></thead>";
     echo "<tr><td>". $data[$i][0] . "</td>";
     echo "</tr><tr><td>" . $data[$i][1] . "<td>";
     echo "</tr>";
     echo "</table>";
     echo "</h2>";
         echo "<div>";
             echo "<h3>Subcategory1</h3>" // Couple sub category
         echo "</div>";

     echo "<div id='printableArea'>";
         echo "<p>AD: ".$data[$i][0]."</p>";
         echo "<p>Descripton: ".$data[$i][1]."</p>";
     echo "</div>";
     echo "<input style='float: right' type='button' onclick="."printDiv('printableArea')"." value='Print' />"; 
 }
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var parentDivs = $('#nestedAccordion div'),
        childDivs = $('#nestedAccordion h3').siblings('div');

    $('#nestedAccordion h2').click(function () {
        parentDivs.slideUp();
        if ($(this).next().is(':hidden')) {
            $(this).next().slideDown();
        } else {
            $(this).next().slideUp();
        }
    });

    $('#nestedAccordion h3').click(function () {
        childDivs.slideUp();
        if ($(this).next().is(':hidden')) {
            $(this).next().slideDown();
        } else {
            $(this).next().slideUp();
        }
    });
});
function printDiv(divName) {
     var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
     var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

     document.body.innerHTML = printContents;

     window.print();

     document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}
```

CSS:

```
#printableArea{
    display: none
}
```

This code works, as i get print button on each of my accordion. But when i click on any of my print button, and the print preview opens up, data is from the first accordion only. How can i fix this, so the print button has the data from its accordion only.

Comment: You must have unique id's: `<div id='printableArea'>` or use a class name and use `this`

Comment: ^ so since its in a loop, append the number to the div id perhaps

Comment: Also `echo "<input ...onclick="."printDiv(...` is not doing what you think. Should be  `echo "<input ...onclick=\"printDiv(...`

Comment: @developerwjk What do you mean by append the number to the div? Sorry, amateur.

Comment: Like `echo "<div id='printableArea" . $i . "'>";` and `echo "<input style='float: right' type='button' onclick=\"printDiv('printableArea" . $i . "')\" value='Print' />";`

Comment: @developerwjk I have fixed that, and it seems to do what i want to do. Only thing is if i click print button, and then instead of print, click canel on the popup, it freezes my page. I cant click on any of the accordion. Any idea on that?

Answer (score 0):

Using `window.print()` prints the window so it won't target your accordion.

Try this plugin [`printElement()`](http://projects.erikzaadi.com/jQueryPlugins/jQuery.printElement/) instead.